# G++ link a header only Boost library for release mode compilation on MAC using Terminal

Tags: c++, macos, boost, terminal

I would like to compile a C++ Mac .dylib using terminal following:

```
g++ -dynamiclib something.o -o something.dylib
```

However I am facing a problem because I do not know how to add a  reference to boost header only library.

I attach the .cpp files I would like to compile to Release mode. These files were the only ones used to compile the written method using XCode. But now I want to learn how to compile this using terminal only.
https://github.com/petrasvestartas/OpenNest/tree/master/Boost

Is there a specific macro to do so?

On windows I reference and compile these two files for boost like this:

```
cl /Ox -I "C:\libs\boost_1_62_0" /LD minkowski.cc
```

Comment: You don't link with header-only libraries. By definition, such libraries consist only of headers and have no binary files to link with. You may get more help if you actually presented the code, the command lines and errors you're getting.

Comment: I added the link to gihub repo, these are only files I use for Xcode compilation. Instead of Xcode I want to learn how to compile the dylib in terminsl only. I know there is no linking. I meant how to add reference to the folder where header files are.

Comment: You will need to consult with the compiler [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). For example, you can use `-I` command line switch to add include directories. You normally don't need to add standard include directories, such as `/usr/include`, as the compiler will use those by default.

Comment: @AndreySemashev With binaries, one knows release version from debug version by the naming convention usually. Is there such a distinction in using header only libraries such as certain boost libraries? Should certain preprocessor macros be defined to obtain release mode performance from boost header only libraries, for example?

Comment: @Tryer Pretty much any code base, including Boost, will be affected by the commonly supported macros such as `_DEBUG`, `NDEBUG` and macros specific to the C++ standard library used with your compiler. Aside from that, there is no Boost-wide macro to select release vs. debug mode for header-only libraries, but there may be library-specific macros that enable certain debug features of the particular libraries. See library documentation for that.